# How to jump between code frames with Vimperator?

Tags: vimperator

Example page to show the problem: http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=15667
There are some scrolled frames with content of .Xresources file.

Now, there is any way to jump between those frames or scroll content?
When I use Vimperator I'm able to move through whole page, but I don't know how to (easy) scroll those frames.

Example page is just an example, there is many many more websites with similar frames.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you want to change the focus to a frame and **not a div**
For frames:

Use brackets [ ] to toggle through different navigation frames on a page.

```
f[ toggles back
f] toggles forward
```

For divs:

Use ;; and then focus some element within the div.

Source: 
http://sheet.shiar.nl/vimperator

Comment: In fact I see, the shortcut is `[f` and `]f`. In your answer I miss the `f`.

Answer (score 0):

the closest (most effective) i could get on the example in the original question is to focus visually nearest element using <kbd>;</kbd><kbd>;</kbd> and then <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Shift+Tab</kbd> to the desired element.

If the target element contains something focusable by 'extendedhinttags' then obviously go for that using <kbd>;</kbd><kbd>;</kbd>

then scroll using <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> keys

Answer (score -1):

WARNING: Works in [Pentadactyl](http://5digits.org/nightlies) only, a fork of Vimperator.

On your example page, I was able to switch focus between the main frame and the code content with <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift-Tab</kbd>.

Comment: I think the key word in the question is **easy**. Yes, you can press Tab 57 times, but that is not what we want when using a _time-saving_ tool like Vimperator.

Comment: We're not talking about tabs, but frames inside a page. Have you seen a page with 57 frames yet, @Neftas?

Comment: I may have misunderstood your solution. On the website the OP referred to, I am not able to switch to the code content by using the Vimperator frame switcher key combination `;f`. If I use the `Tab` key, I have to press it maybe 10 times to get to the code content. If that is not what you meant, I would be grateful if you could explain it more thoroughly.

Comment: @Neftas, if you are at the top of the OP's sample page and the focus is on the main frame (so you can scroll the page with Ctrl-f, the arrow keys or PgUp/Dn), then if you press Tab, the focus jumps straight to the code frame (the one that starts with "! black" and has its own scroll bar), and then you can scroll that frame with the keyboard shortcuts mentioned above. Pressing Tab again brings you to the next code frame, and Shift-Tab brings you back to the main page frame (or the previous code frame).

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce this behavior. When the focus is on the main frame (and I think there is only one frame, at least according to Vimperator), and I can scroll in all manners described by you, when I press the `Tab` key, it shifts focus to the header of the page (the shebang, then 'About', then 'Download', etc.). In fact, I have to press the `Tab` key 18 times (I counted them) to land in the desired code frame. I have no idea why this works for you and doesn't work for me.

Comment: Apparently this shortcut works only in Pentadactyl, a Vimperator fork. Apologies for the confusion caused!